# Vue-Router for Vue3: Revert change in select element after canceling route navigation?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

Sample code:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import {useRoute, onBeforeRouteUpdate, useRouter} from "vue-router";

const route = useRoute();
const router = useRouter()

onBeforeRouteUpdate((to, from, next) => {
  const result = confirm("Are you sure you want to leave? You will lose any unsaved changes.");
  if (result) {
    next();
  } else {
    next(false);
  }
});

async function updateRoute(event) {
  await router.push({params: {state: event.target.value}});
}

const states = ["eating", "idle", "walking"]
</script>

<template>

  <select @change="updateRoute">
    <option value="">Please select one</option>
    <option v-for="state in states" :value="state" :selected="state == route.params.state">{{state }}</option>
  </select>

</template>
```

I'm using `onBeforeRouterUpdate` to prompt the user before navigating away from a selected option. This works as expected except that the `select` element does not revert to the previous selected option when navigation is cancelled.

For example, if I were going from state "eating" to state "walking", my current route parameter would be "eating". If I cancel navigation to "walking", the route parameter would remain "eating" as expected. However, the select element would show "walking" as selected.

- [image: Select element on current selection of "eating"]
- [image: Hovering over "walking" option]
- [image: Navigation confirmation popup]
- [image: Select element on current selection of "walking"]

I can see that the url param still displays "eating" as expected, but the selected option does not reflect that. This also prevents the change event from triggering if I switch back to "eating".

What's the most elegant way to revert the selection to the current router parameter when navigation is canceled? Is there a way I can trigger a reactive event or otherwise re-render the select option to correctly show the selected state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the value of `select` needs to be reset:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import {useRoute, onBeforeRouteUpdate, useRouter} from "vue-router";

const route = useRoute();
const router = useRouter();
const selectRef = ref()

onBeforeRouteUpdate((to, from, next) => {
  const result = confirm("Are you sure you want to leave? You will lose any unsaved changes.");
  if (result) {
    next();
  } else {
    next(false);
    selectRef.value.value = from.params.state;
  }
});

async function updateRoute(event) {
  await router.push({params: {state: event.target.value}});
}

const states = ["eating", "idle", "walking"]
</script>

<template>

  <select @change="updateRoute" ref="selectRef">
    <option value="">Please select one</option>
    <option v-for="state in states" :value="state" :selected="state == route.params.state">{{state }}</option>
  </select>

</template>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm quite new to Vue and it's really helpful to know `ref` can be used this way. I like that this also still provides navigation protection for the back/forward button.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the value of `<select>` already changes even before the user is prompted, and in your code there is no logic for either cancelling the change or reverting it. What you can do is use a `ref` for `<select>` (this would replace your logic which was only one way to a two way bind that you can then utilize to programmatically change the value from your code) and watch it for changes using a [watcher](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html). This way you will be able to intercept any changes and revert them if needed. This is what the updated code would look like:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, watch } from "vue"
import { useRoute, useRouter } from "vue-router";

const route = useRoute();
const router = useRouter();
const selectRef = ref(null);  // we initialize with null

async function updateRoute(event) {
  await router.push({params: {state: event.target.value}});
};

// Won't be triggered until the component is mounted
watch(selectRef, (oldVal, newVal) => {
  const result = confirm("Are you sure you want to leave? You will lose any unsaved changes.");
  if (result) {
    await updateRoute();
  } else {
    // Undo the change
    selectRef.value = oldVal
  }
});

const states = ["eating", "idle", "walking"]
</script>

<template>

  <select ref="selectRef">
    <option value="">Please select one</option>
    <option v-for="state in states" :value="state" :selected="state == route.params.state">{{state }}</option>
  </select>

</template>
```